# AJAX doesn't update post when PHP code stored inside .html function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm having a bit of confusion on why the PHP variables used in the html variable that I inserted inside the .ajax success function doesn't update my post automatically, but works fine when using the data parameter I supplied in the success function.

The reason I prefer inserting data I got from my controller is I need to use some Codeigniter functions, which I cannot do with the latter.

This version of my function where I utilized the data parameter is working fine, but I need to use the word_limiter() function from Codeigniter to reduce the post length

**Version using data parameter**

```
function showFeed() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'ajax',
                url: '<?= base_url()?>feed/showfeed',
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    var html = '';
                    var i;
                    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        html += '<div class="my-3">' +
                        '<h2>'+ data[i]['title'] + '</h2>' +
                        '<span class="post-date text-center px-2 py-1"> Posted on ' + data[i]['created_at'] + ' </span>' +
                        '<p class="my-2">' + data[i]['body'] + '</p><br>' +
                        '<div class="col-6 offset-3">' + 
                        '<img class="post-image" src="<?= site_url();?>/assets/images/posts/' + data[i]['post_image'] + '"></div>' + 
                        '<div class="my-5">' +
                        '<a class="btn btn-dark float-left mr-2" href="http://localhost/ci-socmed/post/' + data[i]['slug'] +'">Read More</a>' +
                        '<form action="http://localhost/ci-socmed/feed/delete/' + data[i]['id'] + '"method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">' +
                        '<input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger float-left mr-2">' +
                        '</form>' +
                        '<a class="btn btn-primary text-white float-left" id="btnEdit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" data="' + data[i]['id'] + '">Edit Post</a>' +
                        '</div></div><div class="clearfix"></div>'
                    }
                    $('#nf-post').html(html);
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Error');
                }
            });
        }
```

**Version with using data from Feed controller**

```
function showFeed() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'ajax',
                url: '<?= base_url()?>feed/showfeed',
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function() {
                    var html = '';
                    html += 
                    '<?php foreach ($feed as $post): ?>' +
                    '<div class="my-3">' +
                    '<h2><?= $post['title'] ?></h2>' +
                    '<span class="post-date text-center px-2 py-1">Posted on <?= $post['created_at'] ?></span>' +
                    '<p class="my-2"><?= word_limiter($post['body'], 30) ?></p><br>' +
                    '<div class="col-6 offset-3">' + 
                    '<img class="post-image" src="<?= site_url();?>/assets/images/posts/<?= $post['post_image'] ?>"></div>' + 
                    '<div class="my-5">' +
                    '<?php if($this->session->userdata('user_id') == $post['user_id']): ?>' +
                    '<a class="btn btn-dark float-left mr-2" href="http://localhost/ci-socmed/post/<?= $post['slug']?>">Read More</a>' +
                    '<form action="http://localhost/ci-socmed/feed/delete/<?= $post['id'] ?>"method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">' +
                    '<input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger float-left mr-2">' +
                    '</form>' +
                    '<a class="btn btn-primary text-white float-left" id="btnEdit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" data="<?= $post['id'] ?>">Edit Post</a>' +
                    '<?php endif; ?>' +
                    '</div></div><div class="clearfix"></div>' +
                    '<?php endforeach ?>'

                    $('#nf-post').html(html);
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Error');
                }
            });
        }
```

**JQuery function for editing post**

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnEdit', function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('data');
            $('#editModal').modal('show');
            $('#editModal').find('.modal-title').text('Edit Post');
            $('#modalForm').attr('action', '<?= base_url() ?>feed/update');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'ajax',
                method: 'get',
                url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>feed/edit',
                data: {
                    id: id
                },
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('textarea[name=edit-body]').val(data.body);
                    $('input[name=post-id]').val(data.id);
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Could not Edit Data');
                }
            });
        });
```

**Feed controller**

```
class Feed extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index($page = 'index')
    {
        if (!file_exists(APPPATH . 'views/feed/' . $page . '.php')) {
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);
        $data['feed'] = $this->Feed_mdl->get_feed();

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('post-text', '', 'required', array('required' => 'Your post is empty.'));

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('feed/' . $page, $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
    }
}
```

**My showfeed() function**

```
public function showfeed() {
        $this->db->order_by('id', 'desc');
        $query = $this->db->get('feed');
        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return $query->result();
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

When I'm using the version which retrieves data from the Feed controller, the database updates it except that I need to refresh the page in order to see whatever changes I made to my post, unlike the other version.

**EDIT**
Just checked that I put the wrong code on the second showfeed() function, where I used the `$data['feed]` object from the Feed controller, in which if I used this version of showfeed(), I'm reloading the page manually in order to view changes I've made in my post. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What PHP variables are you talking about? I don’t see any, all I see is stuff like  `<?= site_url();?>` Hard to tell what you are even trying to ask, with so much code - please try and boil that down to what is actually essential for the problem.

Comment: Hello, I couldn't word that phrase much nicer but the two showFeed() functions on the post shows different results - the first shows the edited post without refreshing the page, while the second needs the page to be refreshed in order to see changes in the edited post.

Comment: both showfeed functions look exactly the same and both use `data` so I'm not sure what you mean by: `utilized the data parameter is working fine`. further, if you are async to get, and then to edit, and the if the edits in php make a change, then you'll have to use ajax to return the changed data and repopulate whatever it is you want to repopulate. e.g. if i have an input field and type `foobar` and hit submit that will stay in the input field if we are using ajax. but if my backend changes it to `foo` then I'll have to get that change and use it to repopulate the input field.

Comment: as it stands 2 people have stated your question in unclear. i would suggest doing your best to edit your question for clarity.